# ZKTeco Biometric attendance machine integration with odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, biometrics

I am trying to integrate `ZKTeco Biometric attendance machine` with odoo. I installed `zklib` package, But when i am trying to install `hr_biometric_machine` module, it is giving me error. ***no module name zklib*** .Someone please tell me how can i integrate it. Is there any other Odoo integration module with ZKTeco Biometric attendance machine. If yes, then how can i get it. Please help me about it I'll be very thankful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a module i found on github

https://github.com/GauravSahu/hr_biometric_machine

it uses the [zklib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zklib/0.1.1) module for communicating with the attendance machine,
i can't guarantee that it will work for all your needs as i've never used it. so be prepared to dive in and write some code or contact the developer if something doesn't work as you expect it to work

Lastly. a simple google search would have gotten you this, always try to search google properly before posting a question

Comment: How to install `zklib` ?

Comment: `pip install zklib`

Comment: i want to install it on windows... is ZKlib place in my_addons or any other place in odoo. please tell me in detail . i have never install any kind of python package

Comment: No...run `pip install zklib` from the command prompt and download the module from github and move it into your addons folder

Answer (score 0):

Install ZKlib lib on your server.

Check below link for ZKlib for windows 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm

Comment: I have already installed zklib in my system .... by `pip install zklib` command. but when i am trying to install `hr_biometric_machine` module, it is giving me error. `no module name zklib`

Comment: even package is installed at this path `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zklib`

Comment: I'm using green odoo: after downloading zklib by using pip install zklib, put the zklib file in runtime/python/lib/python2.7/your_file. restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an integrated free [zk-odoo module](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/hr_zk_attendance/) by [Cybrosys](https://cybrosys.com/) from odoo apps. This module uses an official zk python library for getting key values from the device.

Comment: Well while this might be a solution, but link only answers are not considered good. Please add relevant details to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Cams Odoo module](https://camsunit.com/product/cams-odoo-biometric-integration-module-standard-edition.html) helps to integrate the biometric device where odoo is installed at remote server or device is installed at remote place from the server location. zklib works only if the device and odoo are running in same network, or you have to develop a windows application for integrating the biometric device with remotely installed odoo server, which is taken care by [cams odoo module](https://camsunit.com/product/cams-odoo-biometric-integration-module-standard-edition.html) as inbuit.